# how can i create listview inside a fragment which should show data received by a JSON

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

Like the title says i want to create a listview inside a fragment class.It should receive some data from a JSON and display in the listview. How can i do this?

Can someone show me how to use a adapter for listview and receive data from the JSON so that it displays the data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is several question. You must post what you did so far until that makes to us help you better.
Anyway you must do several work:
1. First create your  [fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)  in MainActvity, then in `OnCreateView` method inflate your layout which contains a listview like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

and your `layout.fragment_main` :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/MainList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

then return your view.

1. In your `OnCreateView` method you must find your listview and create  [JSON](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)  object and then in on `onPostExecute` set your listview adapter like this:

   listview.setAdapter(new MainAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.main_rows, your_object));
2. `your_object` in above have your data which fill in `doInBackground` method.
3. Then you must create a  [custom adapter](https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=cjvrU8nrOauo8werhoLoCg&gws_rd=ssl#q=android+listview+custom+adapter)  and customize it with your object in constructor and in `getview` method inflate your custom view and set your data to related views which you want.